# set_block_property with multiple columns for order by clause

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am working on a form where I have 3 lov fields in data block which represents the column names for the query to sort.

How can I set the `set_block_property` to take more than one column and then sort accordingly.

Eg:

```
set_block_property('table name', order by, column1, column2, column3)
```

at present it is giving error as too many arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Oracle Forms`, `Set_Block_Property` should have three arguments as the following example with `Order_by` clause:

```
declare
  v_order varchar2(500);
begin
  if ( :system.mode = 'ENTER-QUERY' ) then
   v_order := 'column1,column2,column3'
   Set_Block_Property('myblock',Order_By,v_order);
   Go_Block('myblock');
   Execute_Query;
  else
   v_order := null;
   Go_Block('myblock');
   Enter_Query;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: the columns are getting sorted, but now if i sort once and then enter a particular record in enter query mode and then try to sort it is taking the query as: Select column1,column2,column3 from table name where (criteria) order by column1, column2 order by column2,column3. which is giving an error of expression not ended properly.... that is it is taking order by clause twice

Comment: @AnanyaVignesh you may use a variable v_order, refresh during change of query mode.

Comment: Ozhan, the scenario is when the form is opened it shows some records. 
now i select 3 columns for sorting(this is lov in anothere block)
when button is pressed it gets sorted.(working fine).

among the sorted data(will not close the form) i will take a particular data and query it in enter query mode and press ctrl + f11

data is displayed  ..now i again select columns to be sorted and press the button it is giving the error as sql command not properly ended.
so i checked what query is passed and the query was:

Comment: select column1,column2,column3 from <table name> where <where clause> order by <previous order by column> order by <new sorting columns>

Answer (score 0):

Another Option is create the data block based on a custom VIEW, so you could create your query and sort by using ORDER BY.